# Slack API missing_scope for bot requests

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to set channel topics with a bot user token, but I'm getting the `missing_scope` error:

```
{ 
  ok: false,
  error: 'missing_scope',
  needed: 'channels:write',
  provided: 'identify,bot:basic'
}
```

It works if I provide the "OAuth Access Token" (instead of "Bot User OAuth Access Token") from https://api.slack.com/apps/:appId/oauth, but this is a poor solution because the message that gets printed in the channel says that the app installer set the channel topic, not the bot user.

But, [the docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.setTopic) say that bots can call `channels.setTopic` with a bot token, and they don't need `channels:write`:

[image: pic from Slack API docs]

What gives? Are there different kinds of bot tokens? Am I doing something wrong? As far as I can tell, I cannot set additional permissions for my bot user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It also says on the the same documentation page:

> Only user tokens may use this method. Bot user tokens will not work.

And since it does indeed not work as you say I am guessing the mention of the bot token in the above table is a documentation mistake.

If you want to be 100% sure I would advise to ask the Slack team directly.

Comment: oh nooo, that sucks. I got the `is_bot_user` error for other methods (and not for this one) so didn't even think that was a possibility after seeing the part in my screenshot. I will ask Slack.

Assuming they confirm it is a documentation error, is a generic admin user account the best way to do these bot-forbidden methods, if I want to avoid 1) sending users to an authorization flow 2) associating the bot with the app installer, or any other individual human user?

Comment: Yes, a generic admin user is best in my opinion. That is also how we do it on my Slack.

Comment: What did you find out, @tuff?

Comment: It was a documentation error and I ended up following Erik's recommendation and creating a new user account for my bot. It's pretty bad because some of my bot's actions are done by the bot user and some are done by the "human" user.