# When attempting to update topic on slack channel, I get `method_not_supported_for_channel_type`

Tags: postman, slack, slack-api

I am using a bot to post some things to a slack channel. One of the things I need it to do is automatically update the channel's topic.

According to the API documentation, this should do the trick: `https://slack.com/api/channels.setTopic` 
[As per the docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.setTopic), I am passing in my token, channel id and topic.

So the API request looks like this (not sure if relevant, but I'm doing it from postman):

```
POST /api/channels.setTopic HTTP/1.1
Host: slack.com
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
token=MY_BOT_USER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
channel=MY_CHANNEL_ID
topic=Some topic
```

The response I am getting is:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "method_not_supported_for_channel_type"
}
```

I can't seem to find anything about this. What does it mean?
Not sure if worth noting, but I am attempting to do this in a private channel (that the bot is a part of).

So am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack API missing\_scope for bot requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506352/slack-api-missing-scope-for-bot-requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got such error when tried to update the topic for a private channel.

You have to use [`conversations.setTopic`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.setTopic) method to do that. Note, it requires another set of permissions for the token are you using.